# Android App module's build.gradle.kts Unresolved reference error when importing a Kotlin class from an included (composite) module

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-multi-module

In the #NowInAndroid sample app a Kotlin file `NiaBuildType` from an included module is being imported in the app modules build.gradle.kts file.

```
###build.gradle.kts (:app)

import com.google.samples.apps.nowinandroid.NiaBuildType
```

I have tried achieving almost the same result but every time I get `Unresolved reference: au` error.

My package structure in the included build is the same as my app module to enable transitive dependency.
unlike the NIA app I don't have convention plugins in a submodule (convention module is included in the build-logic module which itself is included in the project using `pluginmanager{}`) and only have one included `buildplugin` module.
Here is my file in my included module `buildplugin` :

```
package au.com.myproject
object AppVersion {
    const val versionCode = 1
    const val versionName = "1.0"
}
```

here is the project's `settings.gradle.kts` file:

```
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("buildplugin")
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

This is my `buildplugin` module `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

group = "au.com.myproject.buildplugin"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(gradleApi())

    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0")
    implementation(kotlin("gradle-plugin"))
}
```

and this is my usage in the app modules `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import au.com.myproject.AppVersion

plugins {
    ...
}

android {
    namespace = "au.com.myproject"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "au.com.myproject.pai"
        minSdk = 24
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = AppVersion.versionCode
        versionName = AppVersion.versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
...
```

If I use `buildSrc`instead of composite build, the object can be imported without any issue.

I am not sure what I am missing and have been smashing my head against the wall for a couple of days now trying different approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trick here is that you need to define and reference the plugin explicitly if it's not in `buildSrc`. `buildSrc` acts like an auto-included plugin.

(Looking at the `app/build.gradle.kts` in Now-In-Android, you'll see the plugins registered by the `build-logic` module being pulled in in the `plugins` block.)

To go without `buildSrc`, I think the following should work. (They're similar to an included plugin I've defined in a build)

1. In your `buildplugin/build.gradle.kts`, add

   ```kotlin
   // Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
   // SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

   // at top
   plugins {
       `java-gradle-plugin`
   }

   ...

   gradlePlugin {
       plugins.register("buildplugin") {
           id = "buildplugin"
           implementationClass = "au.com.myproject.buildplugin.BuildPlugin"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a `BuildPlugin` if you don't already have one. Something like

   ```kotlin
   // Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
   // SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
   class BuildPlugin: Plugin<Project> {
       override fun apply(project: Project) {
           // register tasks, create extensions if needed
       }
   }
   ```

   (I'm not positive you need `implementationClass` and the plugin class if you don't need to register tasks or create extension...)
3. Your `settings.gradle.kts` looks good; it includes `buildplugin` during the build and makes it visible to other modules.
4. Explicitly use the plugin in your `app/build.gradle.kts`

   ```kotlin
   // Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
   // SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
   plugins {
       ...
       id("buildplugin")
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Scott! 
The trick did the job. I added one of my custom plugins in the plugin section of the `app/build.gradle.kts` and it now recognises the files in the "buildplugin" included module.
I thought having it only as included build should grant access for other modules to access its file but seems that wasn't the case.